# SVN : Export modified files of revisions committed with specific comment

Tags: svn

I'm using SVN commit comments to associate some keywords to the commited files. I'm trying now to find all commited files - in any revision - having a specific keyword in the comment. Is it possible ?

Thanks by advance !

EDIT for more info : I can use TortoiseSVN (from my local, Windows Seven 64bit) or Command Line (from our integration server, linux)

Edit again : "show log" in tortoise don't let me searching from any date. Right now I can't search from last year... but only from 15/02/2012... Any way to fix that ?

=============================================================================

FINAL ANSWER :
I finally made it work as I wanted. I wanted to get all these logs to use them for svn exports. The final script is named ExportAllRevisionsFromKeyword.sh :

```
    #!/bin/sh
    if [ ! $1 ];then echo "No keyword specified. Needs for example a ticket number : PROJECT-XXX. The command will be : ./SearchCommitsFromComment.sh PROJECT-XXX";exit;fi
    cd /root/PROJETS/myproject/
    SEARCH=$1
    echo "Searching revisions committed with keyword "$SEARCH
    svn log | awk '{
      if ( $1 == "------------------------------------------------------------------------") {
        getline
        REVISION = $1
      }
      else {
        if (match($0, SEARCH)) {
          print "Keyword found in " REVISION ". Export coming..."
          system("./var/batchesFolder/svnxport.sh . " substr(REVISION,2) " var/batchesFolder/sorties/svnExports/" SEARCH)
        }
      }

    }' SEARCH="$SEARCH"
```

As you can see I'm calling another script. It was inspired by [Julien Falconet's tutorial](http://www.falconnet.fr/Subversion-export-des-fichiers.html), named svnxport.sh :

```
    #!/bin/sh
    # svnxport.sh
    # Export only modified files in SVN
    #
    #  Copyright (C) 2009 by Julien Falconnet
    #  http://www.falconnet.fr
    #
    #  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    #  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    #  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
    #  any later version.
    #
    #
    #BEWARE : This script does not operate correctly with files whose filename contains spaces
    # tests for parameters
    if [ ! $1 ];then echo "svnxport : No source specified. Needs : source revision target_directory";exit;fi
    if [ ! $2 ];then echo "svnxport : No revision specified. Needs : source revision target_directory";exit;fi
    if [ ! $3 ];then echo "svnxport : No target_directory specified. Needs : source revision target_directory";exit;fi
    # check if the target_directory allready exists
    #if [ -d $3 ];then echo "svnxport : target_directory '$3' allready exists. Remove it or change target_directory parameter.";exit;fi


    # we use svn diff to select changed files between $2-1 and $2 revisions and only keep those updated or added.
    sourceDir=$1
    revision=$2
    previous=$(($revision - 1))
    targetDir=$3
    escapedSourceDir=$1
    if [ $escapedSourceDir == '.' ]
    then
      escapedSourceDir='\\.'
    fi


    echo "Processing : source($sourceDir), revision($revision), target_directory($targetDir)"

    # Then the 'for' separate status from filename (here is the problem with file with blanks)
    for myfile in `svn diff -r $previous:$revision --summarize $sourceDir | grep -e '^M ' -e '^A '`
    do
    if  [  "$myfile" = "M"  -o  "$myfile" = "AM" -o "$myfile" = "A" -o "$myfile" = "." -o -d $myfile ]
    then
        # we ignore the status, and the directory to update
        continue
    else
        #we focus on true changed files
        #first we create needed directories for the current file
        #note that we use a relative directory system
        outfile=`echo $myfile |sed "s|$escapedSourceDir||g"`
        dir="$targetDir/$outfile"
        mkdir -p $(dirname $dir)
        #then we export the file
        svn export --force $myfile $targetDir/$outfile >> /dev/null
        echo "export $targetDir/$outfile "
    fi
    done
    # List other files. Changed but not exported. Mainly the deleted ones.
    # Usefull to know which files should be removed and follow weird comportment
    #echo "Watch for : "
    #svn diff -r $previous:$revision --summarize $sourceDir | grep -v -e 'M ' -e 'A ' |sed "s|$sourceDir||g"
    echo $'\n'
```

And now, the only action to do is cd into my versionned website root, and call 
`./path/to/scripts/ExportAllRevisionsFromKeyword.sh PROJECT-XXX`

It will search any revision committed with comment containing "PROJECT-XXX" keyword, and will export the HEAD revision of files modified by that revision into a new folder : `path/to/scripts/sorties/svnExports/PROJECT-XXX`

I need to say that Nishant was very helpful with the link he gave to me. Thank you so much ! :)

Comment: which client are you using? TortoiseSvn or Command Line or any other ?

Comment: I can use TortoiseSVN (from my local, Windows Seven 64bit) or Command Line (from our integration server, linux)

Comment: Some weakeness in script detected. 1. svn log have empty lines, which gawk condider **lines** (1-st else will too soft) 2. `if ( $1 ==` is suboptimal and error prone - `if (NF < 2)` suggested 3. For `svn log` " Multiple ... '-r' options may be specified", so - I think, combine command-line parameters for **single** svn log after gawk will be better and faster than do a lot of svn log inside

Comment: I figured out that these multiple logs weren't optimal.
Anyway, my final will is to export the modified files. I managed to export it revision by revision. Original post edit in progress for more info about it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like

```
  svn log | grep <my comment>
```

Or [do something like this](http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2009/04/23/quick_way_searching_comments_from_svn_using_bash_script.html)

Comment: The awk seems very powerful. I'd like to try it but I need it to print file paths from repository root. I'm noob at Linux... could you help me to add this print into the awk command ?

Comment: Thanks to your link I could use sth lie this :

[see original post for the code]

But this is terribly slow... what is wrong with it ?

Comment: this is because log pulls out very LOOOOOOOOOOONG history.

Comment: you can try `svn log -l 100` this will just pull out last 100 entries.

Comment: 100 isn't enough. We are like 15 devs working on this repo.
Sometimes a ticket isn't exported for ages.... and someday it's the day, client asks for us to deliver... I have no idea about the time or the revisions intervals... could be like weeks or months !!
Anyway, I figured out what is so long : the svn log loop !! I replaces by some kind of export (another script exporting only modified files). It's wayyyyy better. Keep an eye on my original post, I'll explain in fex minutes :)

Comment: Is there a way to limit results by date ?

Answer (score 8):

With Tortoise SVN, you can find easily your commit :

Right click => SVN Checkout => Show log

A new window will open and thère, you would find a text aera, enter your keyword and tortoise will automaticaly find your commits.

Now if you don't use Tortoise, sorry for this useless answer.

Comment: That's almost what I need BUT there are some "from/to" dates. I'd like to search from any dates, like 1 year ago. Tortoise only allow me to search from 15/02/2012... not before :(

Comment: Actually, TortoiseSVN allows you to search any dates; you are being restricted to start from 15/02/2012 because that is the earliest date in your latest 100 log messages (TortoiseSVN's default). To search all log messages enter your search term then select the `Show All` button at the lower left of the dialog. Depending on your repository size that could take some time to process. When the dust clears, you will have all matching files--and your start date will now be back to the creation date of your repository.

Answer (score 1):

The proposal on the rights of a good joke:

In order to perform complex queries on SVN-repo use:

- Mercurial (templating + revsets)
- HGSubversion (Subversion access)
- on Linux-box (bash, piping, Tux-tools)

In your case (files from revision with keywords) you'll get something like

`hg log --templates "{files}\n" -r "keyword(word)"`

or, maybe, even

`hg log --template "{join(files, '\n')}" -r "keyword(word)" | sort -u`

(latest template must work, but doesn't work for me, now)

Comment: Sadly, I can't install anything else on the server. Creating a script is ok, but not installing new packages.

Comment: @xbb - you can get it locally, lost only p.3 from benefits list

Comment: My local is Windows, shame on me

Comment: @xbb - I **use** Mercurial **on Windows too** (over TortoiseHG)

Answer (score 0):

Try using it's **Show Log** window which will shows up all the committs made. Now just you need to filter it using your specific comment on the above text box.

Comment: Which show log window ? Where ? Which OS / tool ?
Edit : Ok you are talking about tortoise. Please look at Bruno Fedrigo's post to get my feedback about tortoise search